# If $T$ is a maximal $L$ theory such that every finite subset of $T$ is consistent, then either $\sigma \in T$ or $\lnot \sigma \in T$.

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

Prove without using compactness that if $T$ is a maximal $L$ theory such that every finite subset of $T$ is consistent, then either $\sigma \in T$ or $\lnot \sigma \in T$. Here, by maximal, we mean maximal with respect to this property.

Attempt:

Let $T$ be an $L$-theory with the given property and fix an $L$ sentence $\sigma$. Suppose both $\sigma, \lnot \sigma \in T$. Then $S = \{\sigma, \lnot \sigma \} \subseteq T$ is a finite subset of $T$, so $S$ is consistent. Thus there exists a model of $S$, say $\mathcal{S}$ such that $\mathcal{S}$ satisfies both $\sigma$ and $\lnot \sigma$. This is impossible, so we conclude that for any $L$ sentence $\sigma$, at most one of $\sigma, \lnot \sigma \in T$.

Suppose $\sigma, \lnot \sigma$ are both not in $T$. Then consider $T_1 = T \cup \{\sigma\}$ and $T_2 = T \cup  \{\lnot \sigma\}$. $T$ is contained in $T_1$ and $T_2$ and it is maximal, so it must be that $T_1, T_2$ each contain finite subsets which are not consistent. These subsets must contain $\sigma, \lnot \sigma$ respectively because otherwise they would be finite subsets of $T$, which are consistent by assumption. Thus we can write them as $T' \cup \{\sigma\}, T'' \cup \{\lnot \sigma\}$ resp.

I am not sure how to proceed from here. Any hints would be great!

Comment: First part: Suppose both σ,¬σ∈T. Then S={σ,¬σ}⊆T is a finite subset of T tha is inconsistent. Contradiction.

Comment: Second part: the two are supersets of T: thus T is not maximal. But... you have to prove that at least one of them is consistent.

Comment: If $T'\cup\{\sigma\}$ and $T''\cup\{\lnot\sigma\}$ are finite, inconsistent theories, then $T'\cup T''\subseteq T$ is a finite, inconsistent theory.

Comment: Why is that theory inconsistent @spaceisdarkgreen?

Comment: @John Thought you were asking for hints!

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Is this correct: $T' \cup T'' \cup \{\sigma\}$ is inconsistent because it is a superset of $T' \cup \{\sigma\}$ and  $T' \cup T'' \cup \{\lnot \sigma\}$ is inconsistent because it is a superset of $T'' \cup \{\lnot \sigma\}$. Thus $T' \cup T''$ must be inconsistent, otherwise if a model existed, then it would satisfy either $\sigma$ or $\lnot \sigma$, so one of $T' \cup T'' \cup \{\sigma\}$, $T' \cup T'' \cup \{\lnot \sigma\}$ would be consistent?

Comment: @John Yes that is right. (Also, in case the previous interaction makes you think I’m the downvoter, I’m not, and I’m sorry if my previous comment caused someone else to downvote.)

Comment: No, it is quite all right. I was becoming impatient since I've been working on it for some time now, but I'm glad you didn't give me the answer straight away. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part, we will prove that $T' \cup T''$ is a finite inconsistent subset of $T$. This contradicts $T$ having only finite consistent subsets, so we will be done.

$T′∪T′′∪\{σ\}$ is inconsistent because it is a superset of $T′∪\{σ\}$ and $T′∪T′′∪\{¬σ\}$ is inconsistent because it is a superset of $T′′∪\{¬σ\}$. Thus $T′∪T′′$ must be inconsistent, otherwise if a model existed, then it would satisfy either $σ$ or $¬σ$, so one of $T′∪T′′∪\{σ\}, T′∪T′′∪\{¬σ\}$ would be consistent.

Note : Supersets of inconsistent theories are inconsistent. If a model exists for $T$, a theory which contains $Q$, then this model satisfies all the $L$ sentences in $T$, so it also satisfies all the $L$ sentences in $Q$. Thus it must be a valid model for $Q$ as well, so $Q$ must be consistent too.